# S3 upload using javascript sdk speed calculation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS javascript SDK to upload a file to S3 using multipart upload.

```
// Use S3 ManagedUpload class as it supports multipart uploads
  var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: albumBucketName,
      Key: photoKey,
      Body: file,
      ACL: "public-read"
    }
  });
```

But I would like to also show the speed at which the upload is happening in the UI. Document doesn't provide any API to get the speed. So would like to know how to calculate the upload speed.

regards
Achuth

Answer (score 1):

```
.on('httpUploadProgress', function(e) {
   console.log(e.loaded);
});
```

You can use `.on` listner , and `e.loaded` will provide you the uploaded bytes value, which can be used to calculate percentage of upload.

```
new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: albumBucketName,
      Key: photoKey,
      Body: file,
      ACL: "public-read"
    }
}).on('httpUploadProgress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.loaded);
});
```

Comment: upload progress is fine, I need to find the upload speed.

Comment: You need to calculate the upload speed yourself. Calculate the difference between two successive events and get the speed.